# Как разместить Toolbar на дочернем окне Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Можете пожалуйста показать мне как разместить Toolbar на дочернем окне Tkinter на примере моего кода?

Вод дочернее окно:

```
class mGui1(tk.Toplevel):  #La finestra principale
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('R6S App | 1.000.2')
        self.geometry('800x700')
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Background.jpg"))
        self.panel = Label(self, image=self.img)
        self.panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="no")
```

Код: http://dropmefiles.com/TRvmS

[image]

Пример "Toolbar" который я хочу добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так меню наследуется из основного окна в дочернее при помощи `window.config(menu=m)`

```
from tkinter import *


def top():
    window = Toplevel()
    window.title('R6S App | 1.000.2')
    window.geometry('800x700')
    window.config(menu=m)
    window.panel = Label(window, text='Toplevel')
    window.panel.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x700')
m = Menu(root)
context_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)
fn = Menu(m, tearoff=0)
m.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fn, font='Times 10')
fn.add_command(label='Open', font='Times 12', command=top)
fn.add_cascade(label="Open Recent", menu=context_menu)
for name in ("file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"):
    context_menu.add_command(label=name)
fn.add_command(label='Exit', font='Times 12')
fm = Menu(m, tearoff=0)
m.add_cascade(label="About", menu=fm, font='Times 10')
fm.add_command(label="Help", font='Times 12')
root.mainloop()
```